# when i scroll up the tableview, the tableview cell row height is changed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, height, cell

I make chatting app with a dynamic tableview cell. 
but there is a problem. 
tableview cell's height is fit with content's height at first time, 
but when I scroll it up and down, it changes it's height automatically.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it is becuase of reusing cell. Did you set every single cell's height? or using UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: @JWC I use  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension like this.

Comment: Please add your cell `xib` constraint screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the label with top, bottom constraints wrt cell. It will resize cells according to content.

Answer (score 0):

first remove estimatedRowHeight function and set and fix height of your content and then add this line in tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
   return xxx;
}
```

*xxx is your float value how much you want to give height of your cell